# How to convert sync method to async method in Java 1.4

Tags: java, java1.4

I need to convert a sync method like next:

```
method (String, String, Object)
```

to an async method.

The main problem is that we work with Java 1.4 and I can't use Executor, Future, ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a callback interface (if one isn't already available) and make your method take the interface as a parameter. The method will go off and do its work, and when it's finished, it calls the callback.

Example:

```
int synchronousMethod(int arg0, String arg1) {
    int result = doStuff();
    return result;
}
```

becomes

```
void asynchronousMethod(int arg0, String arg1, Callback callback) {
    try {
        int result = doStuff();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        callback.onFailure(t);
        return;
    }
    callback.onSuccess(result);
}
```

where `Callback` is something like

```
interface Callback {
    onSuccess(int result);
    onFailure(Throwable t);
}
```

It's preferable to use generic types for the `Callback` result (GWT, for example, uses a generic `AsyncCallback<ResultType>` that is identical to the interface above), but since generics aren't available in 1.4, you can either use `Object` and cast or have different `Callback` interfaces for different returns. Compare with any of the `*Listener` interfaces in Swing/AWT.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more, I'm new to the thread topic and I lose a lot.

The code that i want become to async is like that:

for (.....)
...
...
methodIWantConvert (String, String, Object);
...
...
End-for;

The method I want to transform is a pretty normal sequential method. Thanks a million.

Comment: Understand.

The only question I have is that my synchronous method returns nothing, is void, could do the following?

public interface Callback {
void onSuccess ();
void onFailure (Throwable t);
}

public void asynchronousMethod (String mode, String alias, OwnBean ownBean, Callback callback)
OwnException throws {
try {
syncMethod (mode, alias, ownBean);
} Catch (Exception e) {
callback.onFailure (e);
return;
}
callback.onSuccess ();
}

Comment: Right. If it's `void`, then you have an empty `onSuccess` parameter list.